# SPARQL - How do you use count?

Tags: count, aggregate-functions, sparql

I have this query

```
SELECT ?s WHERE {?a <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/topic_interest> ?s}
```

which returns

```
aaa
aaa
aaa
bbb
bbb
ccc
```

However, I want to display it as

```
aaa | 3
bbb | 2
ccc | 1
```

I am using dotnetrdf. This is what i tried

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?s) WHERE {?a <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/topic_interest> ?s}
```

and this just gives me the number of rows there are which is 3080.

Can you tell me how to make it right?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because COUNT(*) simply counts result rows for each group

If there is no GROUP BY clause in your query then there is one implicit group of all results hence you just get the number of rows.

If you add a GROUP BY to your query like the following example you should get the result you want:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?count)
WHERE
{
  ?a <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/topic_interest> ?s}
} GROUP BY ?s
```