# Binding the Result of an Aggregate Function to a Projected Variable

Tags: aggregate-functions, sparql

I am trying to count the number of values for a given property and output each of the retrieved resources along with that number. I am trying to use `BIND` to store the result value of the `COUNT` function in a variable and project that variable to my results. However, that value seems to be empty and I do not understand why that is.

My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?a ?c
WHERE {
  ?a <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?b.
  BIND(COUNT(?b) AS ?c).
}
LIMIT 100
```

I think I will have to group by `?a`, though I am not sure yet how to proceed when I want to do that for several properties, but that is not the concern of this question: For now, I simply want to find out why `?c` appears to be empty.

Shouldn't - for now - there be exactly one label per resulting row? If so, why isn't the literal `1^^xsd:integer` bound to `?c` - or at least some high number representing the total (ungrouped) number of labels (similarly to what happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315151/sparql-how-do-you-use-count)) -, for example on the following endpoints:

- [Austrian Ski Team](http://vocabulary.semantic-web.at/PoolParty/sparql/AustrianSkiTeam)
- [UniProt](http://beta.sparql.uniprot.org/)
- [Europeana/Forest](http://europeana.ontotext.com/sparql)

I am aware the feature I am looking for may not be supported by some or all of these implementations - but if so, it seems unusual that the `COUNT` is simply "swallowed" without an error message (I did get an error message on some other endpoints for the syntax).

Thus, my question is: **Why is the return value of `COUNT` empty?**

- Is the `COUNT` function in that position not recognized by the endpoints?

  - As it seems to be syntactically valid there, is that a shortcoming of current SPARQL engines, or is that by design?
- Is the `COUNT` function evaluated only later (and if so, why doesn't it at least return something like `0`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query isn't actually legal. There's a [SPARQL query validator at sparql.org](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), and it reports a syntax error on `count`:

> #### Syntax error:
>
> Line 4, column 8: Aggregate expression not legal at this point

I can't speak as to why some engines aren't choking on it.  A number built in SPARQL functions can produce errors, and that typically ends up binding variables to seemingly empty results. Perhaps some SPARQL engine developers took this one step farther and make calls to missing functions return an error (which looks like an unbound variable).  That's probably going to be a case by case investigation, and you'll need to contact developers of those products separately.

At any rate, you probably want to end up writing a query more or less like the following.  You can use `(aggregate-function(args) as variable)` in the projection portion of the query, and that's how you can bind the number of `?b`s per `?a` to `?c` once you've grouped by `?a`.

```
select distinct ?a (count(?b) as ?c)
where { ?a rdfs:label ?b }
group by ?a
```

Comment: Indeed, that's the error I got from the other endpoints I mentioned in my question. I think I was overconfident on this working with `BIND` after reading "You need to use `BIND(COUNT(?x) as ?count)` or some similar syntax." [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bigdata/forums/forum/676946/topic/5173545) and after seeing in the SPARQL 1.1 spec that the [grammar suggested using the aggregate functions in `BIND` would be syntactically legal](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rBuiltInCall). I see. I'll try and restructure my queries to feature nested subqueries then.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't see how nested subqueries are relevant here.  They're not used in my solution or in your original query.  The discussion you linked to was talking about the problem that you can't do `select count(?x) ...` but rather have to name the variable with `select (count(?x) as ?something) ...`.  Some endpoints _do_ permit the first and will generate a name, even though it's non standard.  It's down at the moment, but I think DBpedia's endpoint (Virtuoso) will do that, for instance.

Comment: My actual queries, not the simplified one for the purpose of this question, do quite a bit more with the result of `COUNT`. The projection was just added for debugging purposes; actually, I'm using the `COUNT` values in `FILTER` expressions to, for example, retrieve properties with a given minimum number of different values.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ah, yes, then you'll probably need some subqueries.  Note that you _can_ filter on aggregate values using `having`.  E.g., `select ?a (count(?b) as ?c) where { ... } group by ?a having (?c > 100)`.

Comment: Thanks, I've come across `HAVING`. Not sure whether it is flexible enough for my purposes yet; I'll have a try.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Er, well, I don't think you can do `...group by ?a having (?c > 100)`, but you can do `...group by ?a having (count(?b) > 100)`.