# SPARQL average instances

Tags: sparql, average

Is there any way to find the average, min, and max number of instances per class? I have found this:

```
SELECT (count(?instance) as ?no) 
WHERE {
    ?instance a ?class .
}
group by ?class
order by desc(?no)
```

Comment: sub-SELECT query: `SELECT  (AVG(?ǹo) AS ?avg) (MIN(?no) AS ?min) (MAX(?no) AS ?max)
WHERE
  { SELECT  (COUNT(?instance) AS ?no)
    WHERE
      { ?instance  rdf:type  ?class }
    GROUP BY ?class
  }`

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there.

Your current query returns the number of instances per class, e.g.

```
+-------+
|  no   |
+-------+
| 33054 |
| 64239 |
| 28675 |
+-------+
```

Now, what you want is to compute come aggregates on this intermediate results.
Fortunately, SPARQL 1.1 allows for sub-queries, i.e. we can directly reuse the result of your query inside another query and simply use the corresponding aggregate functions:

```
SELECT (AVG(?no) AS ?avg) 
       (MIN(?no) AS ?min) 
       (MAX(?no) AS ?max) 
WHERE { 
 SELECT (COUNT(?instance) AS ?no) 
 WHERE { ?instance rdf:type ?class }
 GROUP BY ?class 
}
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------+-------+-------+
|          avg          |  min  |  max  |
+-----------------------+-------+-------+
| 41989.333333333333333 | 28675 | 64239 |
+-----------------------+-------+-------+
```

Note, I removed the `ORDER BY` as it wouldn't contribute to the final result here. In addition, you can see that no `GROUP BY` is necessary as we're computing the aggregates on the only existing column.

Comment: AKSW, thank you! IMHO, the reason why another `GROUP BY` is not needed is rather that if there is no `GROUP BY` clause, then there is one default group of all results (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9315704). @iMBLISH, for better understanding, you might add something like `GROUP BY ?foobar` to the query. Also, you do not count "empty" classes (if they exist), this can have impact on the value of `?avg`.

Comment: Ok, for empty classes you would need the existence of some schema triple like `?class  a owl:Class .` or the occurrence in any other class axiom (e.g. `rdfs:subClassOf`) - it depends on the ontology indeed.